# I want to use vue.js on Laravel 9 but it doesn't work with me

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I've used the following codes:

composer require laravel/ui

php artisan ui vue --auth

npm install

npm run dev

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing it wrong. It is changed to breeze. [read](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/starter-kits) it.

```
php artisan breeze:install
 
npm install
npm run dev
php artisan migrate
```

After that

```
php artisan breeze:install vue
```

Comment: thank you it works but I must write this => composer require laravel/breeze --dev before all stuff that you wrote  and thank you again

Comment: Thak you for the response, and marking it as an answer. Have a nice day.

Answer (score 2):

I've fixed the problem following the steps below

```
composer require laravel/breeze --dev

php artisan breeze:install
 
npm install
npm run dev
php artisan migrate
```

after that

```
php artisan breeze:install vue
```

then

```
npm install
npm run dev
```